# Возникает 504. Как увеличить производительность

Tags: веб-сервер, администрирование

При импорте большого файла возникает 504 ошибка
Сервер на centos Стоит. В качестве визуального интерфейса стоит vesta panel

Поставил в настройках php.ini

```
max execution time 300
memory_limit 1280m
```

по идее сервер 504 не должна выдаваться в течение 5 минут, так как именно это время выполнения указано в php ini, но импорт все равно обрывается после 30 секундного ожидания.

В настройках сервера я вообще нуб, может быть еще какие то важные настройки есть? которые можно прописаь, или увеличить какие нибудь параметры